# Ways to upload files from mobile app to S3 bucket without the management console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, image-uploading

I wanted to know if I can accomplish my aim of uploading files or large files from my mobile application to my s3 bucket without login into my amazon console. If there is no way to do this, then. How can I upload files once logged in without the annoying web view? Se what others tried.

[Should I upload files to Amazon S3 from mobile devices or from my server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147709/should-i-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-from-mobile-devices-or-from-my-server)  Thanks.

What I need to achieve:

1. Upload files to S3 with no hassles.
2. Download files when needed with no hassles.
3. Able to upload large files on S3.
4. I really don't want to mess with access key and authentication key. Well if I can at least hide them form onlookers that will be fine.

If you can share all the possible file upload implementation in the mobile application scenario that will be great thanks.

Comment: Please add more details about your mobile app (platform, technologies used)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SDK for AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/?nc1=f_ls). It must be an application developed in some programming language available for AWS and be able to access the credentials to connect to S3 and work like an interface between the app and the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

All AWS services can be accessed programmatically via an API. In fact, this is the recommended method for using AWS services.

Mobile applications can certainly communicate directly with Amazon S3.

You will want to secure data stored in S3 so that only **authorized and authenticated** users can access it. This can be accomplished by having the mobile application authenticate with your own back-end service that handles authentication. Alternatively, you could use [Amazon Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html) to handle authentication. This way, your app will handle authentication with AWS and users will never see AWS-specific credentials.